# How can i change the text color of switch widget in Android? I check the boolean value and set the text value and color but code is not working

Tags: android

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
    rotation = checked;
    if(checked){
        switchRotation.setText("h");
        switchRotation.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    else{
        switchRotation.setText("j");
        switchRotation.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
```

//        updateSwitchStatus();
    }
this code is not working how can i set the text color ?

Comment: Does the text change?

Comment: no . the the text never change . I put a debug but its not working?  Should i make a drawable file to change the text color?

Comment: What do you mean "its not working"? If the text is not changed, then `onCheckedChanged()` is never called. You will need to post more code in order to get any help. In particular, show the XML for this checkbox, the class which contains `onCheckedChanged()`, and how you set up the listener.

Comment: i have just done it using this line .
switchRotation.setSwitchTextAppearance(mContext,R.style.SwitchTextOnAppearance);

Comment: Please show the declaration for `switchRotation` and edit your question with the other details I requested.